# How to extract output values from piecewise linear regression in segmented package

Tags: r, regression

I am using the segmented package to run a piecewise linear regression.  My regression model is called fmod, and I use:

```
fmod$psi[1]
```

to extract the first breakpoint from the summary. To view the slopes of each piece of the regression, I use:

```
slope(fmod)
```

and to view the intercepts of each piece, I use:

```
intercept(fmod)
```

However, I am unable to extract a single slope estimate or intercept estimate from the output. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R, not statistics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the help, in general it is supposed to return a list of matrices

For a simple segmented regression, it looks like `slope` appears to return a single element list, which itself contains a matrix.

So `slope(fmod)[[1]][i,j]` will return the i,j element of the first matrix in the list. You can pull out whole rows or columns of the matrix as you would normally.

`intercept` works similarly.

Use `str` to examine objects and see what they consist of and help to see what they're supposed to contain.